# How can I proxy couchDB as a sub-diectory with lighttpd?

Tags: proxy, lighttpd, couchdb

I have a sub-directory on my web server (lighttpd) that I want to point at a CouchDB instance running on the same machine. I tried using mod_proxy but it sends along the whole request, like a proxy should, *I know!*

So:

```
// What happens:
Lighttpd:  http://localhost/couchdb/some_request
    |
    V
CouchDB: http://localhost:5984/couchdb/some_request

// What I want to happen:
Lighttpd: http://localhost/couchdb/some_request
    |
    V
CouchDB: http://localhost:5984/some_request
```

Is there any way to make this setup work?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it should be fairly easy. Take a look at: [Rewrite URL before passing to proxy Lighttpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/135770/rewrite-url-before-passing-to-proxy-lighttpd).